# How to specify keys in React Bootstrap table

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

Using React Bootstrap table, I'm getting the warning `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.`  I've read about how this is necessary for lists, but not sure where I'm supposed to set a key for a Table?  My table looks something like this

```
 <Table size="sm" responsive="sm" bordered hover striped>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Col1</th>
                    <th>Col2</th>
                    <th>Col3</th>
                    <th>Col4</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                { histories.map((h) => (
                    <tr>
                        <th>{ h.col1} </th>
                        <th> { h.col2}</th>
                        <th> { h.col3}</th>
                        <th>{ h.col4}</th>
                    </tr>
                )) }
                </tbody>
            </Table>
```

Comment: the key can be anything, even hard coded if it's important to get rid of the warning (`<th key="1">Col1</th>`). If you have data you're iterating over it can be the id, the name, or whatever.  Or if you really want to go all out you can generate a uuid for each item.

Comment: if `histories` have an id, you could do `<tr key={h.id}>`, that's most likely where the warning is coming from

Answer (score 1):

This would work is there's an id for `histories`.

```
{ histories.map((h) => (
  <tr key={h.id}>
    <th>{ h.col1} </th>
    <th> { h.col2}</th>
    <th> { h.col3}</th>
    <th>{ h.col4}</th>
  </tr>
)) }
```

The key can really be anything (even `h.col1` if you like), as long as it's unique within that list.  It's not super important to have (hence the warning instead of error), but it's definitely is good practice when you're iterating over some data and rendering a list from it, in order to prevent some unpredictable behavior, and to help React do its thing properly.

Comment: Thanks.  The part that I didn't know is that it needed to be part of the <tr>